# Unity crashes after adding a tile in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2d game with a level editor integrated into the game, the script was made with Chatgpt, at first it worked fine, now I select the tile (Debug indicates the correct selected tile), after adding it to the scene/Level unity crashes, I also tried it after compiling the game also crashes. Whatever it may be, the script has an erase and fill function. The script has a variable where I add the tiles that unity creates with the tile palette and that creates category buttons and buttons for each tile.
Script: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e1WwVMOtrgncv6NRXqExZvJjlflNEobi/view?usp=sharing

At first it added the tiles by clicking and dragging, but out of nowhere after some modifications it makes unity crash. Can anyone help me why this happens, I'm a beginner, I don't find many tutorials on 2d level editor, the ones I find are not what I want.

[In-Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfQPG.png)

[In-Game Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLImk.png)

[Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0POe.png)

Comment: usually crashes are caused by infinte loops (there can be other reasons but this is usually the common one)

Comment: I just figured out the problem, it was an infinite loop bug causing the unity to crash. I think it was the mouse click and drag function and add blocks. I separated the eraser and fill tools into separate scripts and redid the tiles script, for now it's working. Sorry for wasting your time, but here it is for someone who has the same problem.